# foreach loop with more than 2 objects

Tags: php, foreach

Example:

```
$get = file_get_contents("example-page-goes-here");

preg_match_all('/yadayada=\"(.*?)\" yadayada=\"(.*?)\" yadayada=\"yadayada\" yadayada=\"(.*?)\">/', $get, $title);

foreach ($title[1] as $link, $title[2] as $img, $title[3] as $title)
{
echo $link."<br>";
echo $img."<br>";
echo $title."<br>";
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: why you try to change foreach syntax ????

Comment: if you check print_r with `$title` for analyze how array is built ?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible.
Please, take a look at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

You could do something like that:

```
<?php

foreach ($title as $index => $item) {
  if ($index == 1) {
    // $item is link now.
  }
}
```

Also, I'd recommend looking at [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php]) documentation page.

Comment: this method only grabbed the 1st string. all three but only 1.

Answer (score 0):

Just expanding on @HankyPanky's answer, you could use `max()` and `count()` to find the longest array length and then perform a loop to that length.

eg.

Get max count like so

```
$count = array();
for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++){
  $count[$i] = count($title[$i]);
}
$maxCount = max($count);
```

and then iterate through and process as required like so

```
for($x = 0; $x <= $maxCount; $x++){
  $link = '';
  $img = '';
  $title = '';

  if(isset($title[1][$x])){
    $link =  $title[1][$x];
  }

  if(isset($title[2][$x])){
    $img =   $title[2][$x];
  }

  if(isset($title[3][$x])){
    $title = $title[3][$x];
  }

  echo $link;
  echo $img;
  echo $title;
}
```

It's not the most efficient way, you could modify it but I think this approach would be the way to go.

Comment: using this method it only displayed the 1st string. all of them but only $link